# Где хранить фотографии для сайта?

Tags: веб-программирование

Делаю статический сайт-галерею с размещением на гитхабе, недавно (сегодня собсна) узнал печальную весть, что репозитории содержат ограничения, такие как 100мб на один загружаемый файл, а общий размер репозитория не должен быть больше гигабайта.
Для кода оно достаточно, пары картинок и svg для сайта - вполне. 
Но что делать, если картинок (в качестве основного контента) будет тысяча или уже больше? Сайт для личного использования, на то он и статический, так что миллиард картинок не будет, но в общем обхвате вес иметь будут. Как в таком случае их хранить, и где - самое главное? Если на облаках (и в каких), не сменятся ли там юрлки? Это будет печально, если 1000 картинок поменяют юрл, а ты потом сиди и в `_data` файле все юрл заного прописывай. Так что такой вопрос стоит сейчас.

Comment: imgur ? https://api.imgur.com/

Comment: Пинтерест, фликр, гугл-диск, дропбох и далее, у всех вышеперечисленных есть API

Comment: @Hardc0re, расскажи о преимуществах тогда, если таковые имеются, о которых ты знаешь по опыту использования.

Comment: @МихаилРебров, я недавно веб изучаю и об API знаю лишь, что это набор функционала, который дается разработчикам, чтобы использовать их сервис для себя. Это может мне подойти? Если, например, я выберу гугл-диск, я смогу это реализовать, если начну копать в этом направлении?

Comment: @VostokSisters, можно гугл диск отдельно как хранилище для фотографий использовать, можно целиком и полностью сделать сайт там.[Документация по API Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/)

Comment: @VostokSisters, то что можно - это факт, но сколько Вы провозитесь с этим без наличия опыта - не знаю.

Comment: @VostokSisters,  у Гугла есть ещё такая тема как Google Сайты... https://sites.google.com/ ...последние по факту тоже на диске хранятся гугловском.

Comment: @МихаилРебров, нет, сайт на гитхабе будет, как я уже сказал)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52256/discussion-between-vostoksisters-and--).

Comment: @VostokSisters если сайт статический (или по крайней мере картинки - статические) - то Amazon S3 - самый надежный и дешевый вариант. Юрлки не поменяются.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

Comment: @МихаилРебров, ещё раз - спасибо) Приглянусь. Сайт статический полностью, а картинки - ну вроде да, правда я не понял что это - статические картинки? Просто картинки для отображения. Сайт-галерея всё-таки. Иногда загружать буду их, как нарисую что-нибудь. И всё)

Answer (score -3):

> Но что делать, если картинок (в качестве основного контента) будет тысяча или уже больше?

Покупать хостинг и делать там сайт.
А если действительно для личного, то у себя на ПК и не выкладывать в интернет.

Потому как любые бесплатные сервисы имеют свойство загибаться.

Comment: Если для личного использования говорится, это не обязательно только я на него буду смотреть)
Смысл в том, что наполнять его буду я, а не другие люди. 
 И нет, хотелось бы без хостинга обойтись.

Comment: Ну если не ценишь своё время (это есть жизнь, на сек.), то можешь играться с неуправляемыми тобой сервисами. Естественно верно решение - хостинг. Или "сервер дома". Но неизвестно что дешевле обойдётся.

Comment: Ну ты можешь тогда не покупать программы майкрософт, не загружать линукс и не пользоваться чем угодно другим из готовых продуктов и сервисов, а всё делать с нуля. Далеко собрался с такими мыслями вообще? :D
Использовать можно всё, если работает как тебе надо. Вопрос вполне конкретен.

Comment: Хостинг - и есть "пользоваться готовым". А про "собираться".. смешно, да :) В профиль заглянуть не судьба? По ссылочкам походить? Лано, не буду мешать заниматься фигнёй. Когда потеряешь свою работу - поймёшь как нужно делать ПРАВИЛЬНО.

Comment: @SeVlad, правильно в твоем понимании это быстро и затратно, зато без фигни, я сразу это понял. Можешь не повторяться ещё раз. А здесь вопрос в том, чтобы не платить за хостинг для статического сайта, который нужен ТОЛЬКО для того, чтобы хранить картинки. В 2017-м году не найдется ни одного такого хостинга для размещения каких-то картинок? Серьезно?